# State A uses B and state B uses A

Tags: angular, ngxs

I create an application that is so complex that I have to divide the state into two smaller ones. Unfortunately, some selectors in state A must read some field from state B, and some selectors in state B must read some field from state A.

For example - 
**State A:**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
@State<{x: number;}>({
  name: "stateA",
  defaults: {x: 0}
})
export class StateA {
  @Selector([StateB])
  public static someSelector(stateA, stateB) {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```

and **State B:**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
@State<{y: number;}>({
  name: "stateB",
  defaults: {y: 0}
})
export class StateB {
  @Selector([StateA])
  public static someSelector(stateB, stateA) {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```

When I try to implement it I get the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'StateA' before initialization`

error disappears as soon as:
 `state A uses B and B doesn't use A` or
 `state B uses A and A doesn't use B`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an issue loading these inter-dependent states in this manner.

For the scenario you describe you could consider using a [Meta Selector](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#meta-selectors) that you define separate from each state class.  This will allow you to combine the states together to form a selector that draws from properties of both states.

```
export class CombinedSelectors {
  @Selector([StateA, StateB])
  static combineThem(stateA, stateB) {
    // do stuff e.g.:
    return stateA.x + stateB.y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for this advice but I think it can be a bothersome when there are more such situations.